# GetOpenFilename behaviour different for version earlier than Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim SPATH As String
    Dim myFileName As Variant

    If MsgBox("Some Question...", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

'Used to open the VO2 report taken from the Metabolic Cart. Will close later
    myFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xls*")
    If myFileName <> False Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileName
    End If

    MultiPage2.Value = 3

End Sub
```

It's job is to search for and open another Excel file while a userform is being run with the workbook it's currently tied to is visible=False with this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False
    UserForm2.Show
    Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True
    Application.Visible = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Also important note: Showmodal for this userform is True

When this is run using Excel 2016, it works no problem (i.e. I am able to use a refedit on the userform while the loaded Excel file is visible to use it on).

On my work computer which has an older version of Excel, the loaded Excel file is invisible (meaning I can't use the refedit I have on the userform).

Does anyone know what may be going on or have a possible solution?

Comment: Did you copy the file from your computer to your work computer? Or did you copy the code to a new file?

Comment: it's currently contained on a USB, same Excel file too. I have teamviewer hooked up so that I could transfer the version I have loaded on my work computer to my computer at home to see if I can load it and run the following code there. Still works no problem on the home computer.

Comment: What version of Excel are you running on the work computer that is having the problem?

Comment: My work computer currently runs Excel 2010

Comment: Hmm... are you able to compile the VBA in Excel 2010 without issue?

Comment: Yeah I get no issues when I compile the project.

Comment: Then I have no idea, unfortunately; hopefully with this extra information someone else will see and be able to help!

Comment: No worries. Yeah I'm hoping so myself. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Since when does `Application.GetOpenFileName` return either `False` or a filename? Can you send me a link that documents this behavior?

Comment: @Ken White Sure, but I'll have to do it when I get home as the site that I found through research that documented this behavior is on my laptop (separate from my computer).

Comment: @Ken White https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-open-workbook/, It's a little ways down on this site.

Comment: Yep. Poorly designed implementation by MS (returning either a boolean or a string - really?). Confirmed with official documentation at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-getopenfilename-method-excel) Thanks for the link. :-)

Comment: @Ken White If you don't mind me ask (being I'm new to VBA coding), Im guessing the link you provided is some kind of documentation stating known bugs/errors with MS excel? I'm only guessing because of this that was on that page:

"Displays the standard Open dialog box and gets a file name from the user without actually opening any files."

Which seems to be the issue i'm facing with Excel 2010. Looks like they fixed it though with the newer version of excel 2016. Thanks for the link also :)

Comment: No, it's not bugs. It's an article by MS staff on use of that function. MSDN is the **M**icro**s**oft **D**eveloper **N**etwork, the official Microsoft technical documentation site. See http://msdn.microsoft.com

Comment: @Ken White Oh ok, thanks for the clarification!